# django versions reversion how to act?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, django-cms

I'm try to open up django-cms a project I didn't work for a while when I

```
  python mange.py runserver
```

I have this error :

```
     Users/Alex/.virtualenvs/jpc_pabulum/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reversion/__init__.py:35: 
     UserWarning: django-   reversion 1.6.1 is intended for use with django 1.4.0. 
     You are running django 1.4.1, so some features, such as    admin integration, may not work.
     Please see https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/wiki/Compatible-Django-   
     Versions"django_version": format_version(django.VERSION[:3]),/Users/Alex/.virtualenvs/jpc_pabulum/lib/python2.7/site-packages/reversion/__init__.py:35: 
     UserWarning: django-reversion 1.6.1 is intended for use with django 1.4.0. 
     You are running django 1.4.1, so some features, such as admin integration, may not work. 
     Please see https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/wiki/Compatible-Django-Versions "django_version": format_version(django.VERSION[:3]),
```

This my

```
pip freeze 


    BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
    Django==1.4.1
    PIL==1.1.7
    PyYAML==3.10
    South==0.7.5
    Werkzeug==0.8.3
    cmsplugin-filer==0.8.0
    cmsplugin-zinnia==0.2
    django-blog-zinnia==0.11.2
    django-classy-tags==0.3.4.1 
    django-cms==2.3
    django-cms-search==0.6.1
    django-debug-toolbar==0.9.4
    django-extensions==0.9
    -e git+https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer.git@ac71bcdc47ac83ddf2ea3cf0e9ff1e1e9f3df1b2#egg=django_filer-dev
    django-form-utils==0.2.0 
    django-haystack==1.2.7
    django-mptt==0.5.2
    -e git+https://github.com/cypreess/django-ordered-model.git@ce6a6b9292d20b30e6b0e76ba84bb29975451d6b#egg=django_ordered_model-dev
    django-polymorphic==0.2
    django-reversion==1.6.1
    django-sekizai==0.6.1
    django-tagging==0.3.1
    django-taggit==0.9.3 
    django-uni-form==0.9.0
    django-xmlrpc==0.1.4
    easy-thumbnails==1.0.3
    html5lib==0.95
    psycopg2==2.4.5
    pyparsing==1.5.6
    pysolr==2.1.0-beta
    pytz==2012d
    wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Im using a virtualenv and virtualwrapper.

UPDATE

I install the reversion and now is validating models fine but I open the page and have this error:

```
   OperationalError at /
   could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options, from most preferable to least:

1. pip install django-reversion==1.6.3
2. pip install Django==1.4.0
3. Check that everything is working and ignore the warning, as it is not an error.

If you choose to upgrade reversion, you might need to do `./manage.py migrate reversion`.

Comment: ok I have an other error now - those two are not related ? are they?

Comment: No, your database server is not running.